# Convert List of enum into array

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, dto

I have this Enum structure `List<Role>`

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
  ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CLIENT;

  public String getAuthority() {
    return name();
  }

}
```

I tried to implement this:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = roles.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(s -> s.getAuthority().toString());

        String s1 = stringStream.toString();
```

Response DTO:

```
public class DTO {

    private String role;
}
```

But I get as a response:

```
{
"role": "java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@7d499cdc",
}
```

I want to return something like:

```
{
"role": [
        ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CLIENT
     ]
}
```

How I can print the response this way?

Comment: There are several terminal operations in a stream which you can use. Please check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java-8-stream-terminal-operations. `.collect()` would be useful for you.

Comment: What is `roles`?

Comment: My bad. Just a variable.

Comment: Just a variable!! contain what? which type?

Comment: For storing  List<Role>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your issue, you can use:

```
String s1 = roles.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(s -> s.getAuthority().toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .toString();
```

---

But I think your logic is not correct, the response Dto should look like:

```
public class DTO {
    private Lis<String> role;
    
    // getter, setter and constructor
}
```

And then your stream should be:

```
List<String> authorities = roles.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(s -> s.getAuthority().toString())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
DTO response = new DTO(authorities);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the object mapper's function `writeValueAsString`. That should ideally solve your problem. `toString()` won't help you here.

```
ObjectMapper ob = new ObjectMapper();
ob.writeValueAsString(roles.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(s -> s.getAuthority().toString()));
```

Something like this will help you.